# Why does NDB context cache set a environment variable?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Looking though the Google NDB code, I can´t quite seem to work out why the context cache sets a environment variable.

The code in quesiton:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py

```
_CONTEXT_KEY = '__CONTEXT__'

def get_context():
  # XXX Docstring
  ctx = None
  if os.getenv(_CONTEXT_KEY):
    ctx = _state.current_context
  if ctx is None:
    ctx = make_default_context()
    set_context(ctx)
  return ctx


(...)

def set_context(new_context):
  # XXX Docstring
  os.environ[_CONTEXT_KEY] = '1'
  _state.current_context = new_context
```

I know what it does, but why? (Speculation on my side removed, I don´t want to mislead answers)

### Update:

The _state is based on this code:

```
class _State(utils.threading_local):
  """Hold thread-local state."""

  current_context = None

(...)
```

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/ndb/utils.py

```
# Define a base class for classes that need to be thread-local.
# This is pretty subtle; we want to use threading.local if threading
# is supported, but object if it is not.
if threading.local.__module__ == 'thread':
  logging_debug('Using threading.local')
  threading_local = threading.local
else:
  logging_debug('Not using threading.local')
  threading_local = object
```

Answer (score 3):

Environment variables are specific/scoped to the request, so that provides a way of getting the context anywhere in your code without having to refer to a specific object/entity or provide a request specific lookup mechanism.

Some environment variables are set before the request is processed from the real environment, app.yaml.

Then for each request the environment variables are set from appengine_config.py , then the WSGI environment for the request, then the handler, and then other components contribute (ie your code may populate the environment), this is specific to each request.

So the environment is considered threadsafe (ie won't leak things across concurrent requests)

Comment: To make sure I understood you correctly: You´re saying the environment variable is used to make the "get/set_context" code thread-safe?

Comment: yes, because the `os.getenv()` result is specific/threadsafe for each request in **appengine**.

Comment: I´ve added the implementation of _state to the question - Should´t that be threadsafe /request specific on its own?

Comment: However the os.getenv() result is not going to be thread safe between threads you create within a request.